# Django send notification based on interaction with object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, notifications

I've a post, where I need to send a notification when it is liked the 1st,5th,10th,25th,50th time. I was looking for an optimal way to this. What I've in mind right now is to store in the model something like

```
first_interaction Boolean
fifth_interaction Boolean
So on..
```

Could there be a better way for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

1. Save in your model the counter of likes and the number of notification sent
2. Send a notification only if counter % 5 is True
3. Add the previous logic in a post_save signal or in the model .save() method

Other notes:

- Up to you to select your favorite among signal or save method
- Saving the number of notification sent can be very useful to ensure you are not sending duplicated notifications, as you can always compare the counter with the tracked number of notification sent.

Comment: I currently have multiple reactions like Facebook, so it has a Reaction Model with a foreign key to that post. Storing a counter would be extra work?

Comment: You can avoid to save the counter in the db e do the counting every time just before sending the notification. But what happens when you receive 20 likes at the same time? Do you send 4 notifications or just one?

Comment: 4 notifications, also it won't be %5 is true, can be 1,5th,10th,25th,100th